# How to sort images into folders, based on resolution?

Tags: sorting, image, resolution

Background: I've got a folder full of saved desktop pictures.  I'd like to put them into folders, based on their resolution - 1024x768, etc.  Creating the folders on the fly is a bonus.  Currently, the images are all in a folder, but some of them are in sub-folders.  I can merge them by hand, if that makes things easier.

I'm using Mac OS X, but I'm not opposed to installing extra apps to accomplish this (MacPorts?), or even using another OS (I've got Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Ubuntu 9 setup right now within VMWare).

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: This is probably a better question for http://superuser.com/ - you can get the password at the stackoverflow blog

Comment: Thanks, Antony!  superuser.com looks like a much better fit. :)

Comment: Instead of a migration to SU, this has been duplicated there... http://superuser.com/questions/17562/how-to-sort-images-into-folders-based-on-resolution

Answer (score 2):

If you speak Python, the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) should do the trick.

```
import Image, os
for filename in os.listdir("/path/to/images"):
    image = Image.open(filename)
```

and from there, you can sort your images based on the `size` member, which is a (width, height) tuple.

Comment: Thank you, Meredith!  I'm still a bit lost, but I think I'm going to take Antony's advice and ask on superuser.com.

Many thanks for the help, though.